# Date key in format YYYYMMDD inverts to DDMMYYYY in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am working with a few tables were I defined a date key as YYYYMMDD. I can see this format in database and visual studio, and in visual studio relations are working properly. But when I go to Power BI all my date keys invert to format DDMMYYYY, with the exception of two tables. Does anyone know why it is happening?
Thanks

Comment: What is the value type in the Power BI column?  Is it a date?  text? number?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not at a computer so I can’t provide screenshots, but basically you can control the way that dates are displayed in the **Modeling** ribbon at the top of Power BI (at least I think it’s called Modeling, it could be called Data or Column or something similar as well). But first you need to click on the column that you want to view/adjust from the side menu to access this ribbon.

Anyway, in this ribbon there should be fields that control data type and data format. If your column has a data type of Date or DateTime, then you can update the **data format** field to display the date as you would like in Power BI.

If for some reason this doesn’t work, you could directly control the date format in [Power Query Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-query-overview) as well I believe.